# Paypal API integration for debit and Credit card with Node JS

Tags: reactjs, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am tiring to add credit debit card integration that are already saved in our database and I don't want user to fill those information to the paypal debit/credit card payment form.

I want to know

1. Is there a way to auto populate information from my database to paypal from?
2. Or how can I use orders API to directly pass the information to the paypal using API integration.

The Paypal really is a mess. Can anyone please help me in the integration.

NOTE  : I am using React JS as front-end and nestjs as back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't populate a form, and storing credit card information in your database is a potentially problematic practice you should review (better to [tokenize/vault](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/vault-payment-methods/vault-sdk/) it) and requires a full PCI self-assessment review.

But as for how to send credit cards to PayPal via an API, if anaccount is enabled for [Advanced Credit and Debit Card](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/#1-enable-your-account) processing, the below might allow you to use the [v2/checkout/orders](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body) API with card details in the `payment_source` object

(Edit: apparently more permissions are needed from PayPal for this)

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "payer": {
        "name":{
            "given_name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe"
        },
        "email_address":"johndoe@buyersemail.com"
    },
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "reference_id": "0000",
            "description": "Transaction description",
            "custom_id": "Optional arbitrary private transaction-related ID/data, 127 chars",
            "soft_descriptor": "Shows On CC statement",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "100",
                "breakdown": {
                    "item_total": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "100"
                    },
                    "shipping": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "0"
                    }
                }
            },
            "shipping":{
                    "name":{
                        "full_name":"John Doe"
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "address_line_1": "123 nowhere lane ",
                        "address_line_2": "Unit 123",
                        "admin_area_2": "San Jose",
                        "admin_area_1": "CA",
                        "postal_code": "95131",
                        "country_code": "US"
                    }
            }
        }
    ],
   "payment_source": {
                "card": {
                    "number": "4032038000494967",
                    "expiry": "2023-04",
                    "security_code":"123",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is asking for a paypal request id .Can I pass anything or if it's unique one how can i generate that. @preston

Comment: Anything not previously used for a different payment.

Comment: The point is I am unable to understand the flow. Why there is so much confusion about the implementation just because the docs are not proper. Could you please show me with some example of yours.

Comment: It's a single API request; the above is in fact an example.

Comment: I want to complete all the process without any user interaction once he has clicked on buy now. I should taked his information from database i.e card information and return him with success. Thats what I want no interaction whatso ever with customer after that.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I configure the card in the app as I am now getting this error.
PAYEE_NOT_ENABLED_FOR_CARD_PROCESSING

Comment: Did you enable the account, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/#1-enable-your-account ?

Comment: yes it's enabled and I am able to pay through card with the SDK. Below is the link from where I am trying to generate access token and provide to the checkout API.
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

Can you just please create a fully tested checkout procedure and provide it as answer with all screenshots. So that I can check all things from there.

Comment: In that case you'll need to contact PayPal; perhaps the same permissions are needed as to use the vault API for storing cards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234801/discussion-between-sanjeev-gupta2812-and-preston-phx).